# Why is my map() not working?

Tags: scala, future, akka-http, spray-client

I have a Akka HTTP service which returns a string, as shown below:

```
val route1: Route = {
    path("hello") {
      get{
        complete{
          println("Inside r1")
          "You just accessed hello"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to understand the difference between map and flatMap

For example, the below code gives me the result as expected:

```
val future1: Future[String] = 
  Http()
   .singleRequest(
      HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET,
                  uri = "http://localhost:8187/hello"))
   .flatMap(testFlatFunc)

def testFlatFunc(x: HttpResponse): Future[String] = {
  Unmarshal(x).to[String]
}
```

But, if I try to replace it with a map, as below I get the output as `FulfilledFuture(You just accessed hello)`

```
val future1: Future[String] = Http()
    .singleRequest(
      HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET,
                  uri = "http://localhost:8187/hello"))
    .map(testFunc)

def testFunc(x: HttpResponse): String={
  Unmarshal(x).to[String].toString
}
```

Why is my map() not working as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about what you do in `testFunc`:

```
def testFunc(x: HttpResponse): String = {
  Unmarshal(x).to[String].toString
}
```

here types are ok, but what you do inside is not.

```
Unmarshal(x).to[String]
```

returns `Future[String]` - it means it is asynchronous result, and its value will appear there in time. It is ok, to use such result type in `flatMap`.

```
val sqrts: Double => List[Double] = x => List(Math.sqrt(x), -Math.sqrt(x))
val numbers = List(4.0, 9.0, 16.0)
numbers.flatMap(sqrts) // List(2.0, -2.0, 3.0, -3.0, 4.0, -4.0)
// results equal to
numbers
  .map(sqrts) // List(List(2.0, -2.0), List(3.0, -3.0), List(4.0, -4.0))
  .flatten    // List(2.0, -2.0, 3.0, -3.0, 4.0, -4.0)
```

Here you can see that flatMap works like map + flatten (except that some containers don't even have to have flatten implemented, e.g. `Future` ;) ).

But why your `testFunc` fails? Basically you take the asynchronous result (`Future[String]`) and you don't wait for the result - you call toString instead which only prints some useless information (`FulfilledFuture(You just accessed hello)`) but not the result itself.

To work around this you would have to do something like:

```
def testFunc(x: HttpResponse): String = {
  Await.result(Unmarshal(x).to[String], 10.seconds)
}
```

this would block and wait at most for 10 seconds for the result to make it synchronous. (That kind of beats the purpose in this case and `map` would be more useful if the result you calculate there was synchronous in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

`map` and `flatMap` difference:

> `flatMap` will collapse one level of nested structure(it calls [fallten](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html#flatten)), like: `List(List(1), List(2)).flatMap(i => i)` will be: `List(1, 2)`

so as your code, `testFlatFunc` and `testFunc` **return type** is `Future[String]`, and `map` and `flatMap` function return type also be `Future[T]`, but `flatMap` will flatten the nest struture, so: `Future[Future[String]]` will flatten to be `Future[String]`. and `map` function will not do this, so:

```
 val future1:Future[String] = Http()
    .singleRequest(
      HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET,
                  uri = "http://localhost:8187/hello")).map(testFunc)
```

return type should be:

```
 val future1:Future[Future[String]] = Http()
    .singleRequest(
      HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET,
                  uri = "http://localhost:8187/hello")).map(testFunc)
```